# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UISearchBar searchTextField]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, uisearchbar

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UISearchBar searchTextField]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8ebaf60cf0'**

How do I know which is this view 0x7f8ebaf60cf0?

I was doing PO 0x7f8ebaf60cf0

and it returns this 140250998770928

Then I needed more info like recursiveDescription but I can't get further. How can I start debugging such a bug?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that `searchTextField` is iOS 13 only. On iOS 12 and before it compiles, runs, and crashes. Just do a global search for `searchTextField` and don’t use it under iOS 12 or earlier.

Comment: Totally makes sense. My Bad. It looks like final answer, just finishing to test it.

Comment: so how can I call the searchBar on my extension for iOS 12? on this func func setTextFieldTextProperties(font: String, size: CGFloat, textColor: UIColor) {
        searchTextField.font = UIFont(name: font, size: size)
        searchTextField.textColor = textColor
    }

Comment: Looks like this searchBar.textField?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0) doesn't work for my UISearchBar extension.

Comment: You can’t. On iOS 12 the text field is not directly exposed thru and property. But that wasn’t the question. The question was the crash and I explained it.

Comment: there you go. But actually the question was about debugging and you went further. Thanks anyway and have a nice day matt.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look https://learnappmaking.com/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-swift-development/

Basically these errors occurs when you try to access an object which is nil.
I think in your case it happens because [UISearchBar searchTextField] ,Here searchTextField is no function.